# filter_out unwanted stuff from variable content in GNUmake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have variables as shown below:

```
TEMP_VARIABLE := proj1 proj2 proj3 proj4
PROJ := proj2
```

I Want to remove all projects i.e (proj1,proj3,proj4) from TEMP_VARIABLE. For that i have below parsing technique in my Makefile.

```
TEMP_VARIABLE  := $(foreach dir,$(TEMP_VARIABLE), $(ifneq $(,$(findstring $(dir),$(PROJ))) $(filter-out $(dir),$(TEMP_VARIABLE))))
```

When i run my make file and try to display `TEMP_VARIABLE` it prints nothing. And noting is there in That variable.

Is there anything wrong in my `foreach` parsing above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

```
$(,$(findstring $(dir),$(PROJ)))
```

It's unlikely that you have a macro called `,`, or `,proj2`. To check for this sort of mistake, always run *make* with `--warn-undefined-variables`. I got:

```
$ make -f a --warn
a:3: warning: undefined variable ','
a:3: warning: undefined variable 'ifneq  proj2 proj3 proj4'
a:3: warning: undefined variable ',proj2'
a:3: warning: undefined variable 'ifneq  proj1 proj3 proj4'
a:3: warning: undefined variable ','
a:3: warning: undefined variable 'ifneq  proj1 proj2 proj4'
a:3: warning: undefined variable ','
a:3: warning: undefined variable 'ifneq  proj1 proj2 proj3'
```

### What You Really Wanted

Life is usually simpler. How about using `$(filter …)`?

```
$ cat a
TEMP_VARIABLE := proj1 proj2 proj3 proj4
PROJ := proj2
TEMP_VARIABLE := $(filter ${PROJ},${TEMP_VARIABLE})
$(error [${TEMP_VARIABLE}])
```

giving

```
$ make -f a --warn
a:4: *** [proj2].  Stop.
```